# Java code to parse any json file irrespective of its format or key

Tags: java, jackson, json

I have been searching from many days but not getting any answer for this. So finally I have come down to this site. Is there any java code or any library which can parse any json file irrespective of its format and without knowing what all keys are present in the json file.

Whatever json file is given it can display all the key value pairs inside it.

Comment: Are you not happy with any of the standard libraries?

Comment: Jackson is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try out Genson http://code.google.com/p/genson/.

You can deserialize the json file into a map if the root is an object (otherwise it is an array and you deserialize to an array).

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader("path/to/your/json");
Map<String, Object> map = new Genson().deserialize(reader, Map.class);
```

Depending on what you want to achieve for better performances you can use directly the streaming api (but it is more code to write). You only want to print the key/values??

Genson has full databinding support and provides some other nice features, have a look at the [wiki](http://code.google.com/p/genson/wiki/GettingStarted).

Comment: Yes I only want the key value pairs

Answer (score 2):

[Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) works very well for this.

```java
 final Map<String, Object> son = objectMapper.readValue(JSON_SOURCE,
      new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {}
 );
```

where `JSON_SOURCE` can be `String`, `Reader`, `File`, `byte[]`, `InputStream` etc. (see: [ObjectMapper documentation](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html))

This code snippet is slightly different from another (similar) answer posted for this question. Note that above uses:

1. Jackson's `TypeReference` instead of a `Class` object
2. the interface `Map` and not a specific implementation (e.g. `HashMap`)